# error 500 setTemplate symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony2

estoy manteniendo una app hecha en symfony 1.4, estuve corrigiendo varias cositas, entre ellas:

Tengo un login que local anda bien, pero en prod me tira error 500, la url es registro/enviarContrasena
[image: error al ingresar a registro/enviarContrasena]

Trabajando en localhost, me aparece un mensaje si fue exitoso o no:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Comparto un poco del código:** 
LoginSuccess.php

```
<div id="recuperarContrasenaForm" class="well" style="display: none; position: absolute; left: -10%; right: auto; z-index: 2">
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="combopaginado">
        <div class="panel-body text-left">
            <form id="contraForm" name="contraForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo url_for("registro/nuevaContrasena") ?>">
                <legend>Modificar contraseña </legend>
                <table  >
                    <tr>
                        <td >Usuario:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="usu" name="usu" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Contraseña anterior:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Contraseña nueva:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password_nuevo" name="password_nuevo" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Repetir contraseña:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password_nuevo_rep" name="password_nuevo_rep" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <div class="botoneraLogin pull-right">
                    <input id="recuperarContrasena" class="btn btn-success" value="Cancelar" style="width: 100px;"
                           onclick="click_showHide(this)"/>
                </div>
                <div class="botoneraLogin pull-left">
                    <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Modificar"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**y el action method**  action_class.php

```
public function executeNuevaContrasena(sfWebRequest $request) {

        $_SESSION["usuario"] = "";
        unset($_SESSION["usuario"]);

        $this->errors = array();
        $this->notices = array();
        if($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
                $password       = $request->getParameter("password2");
                $usuario        = $request->getParameter("usu");
                $password_nuevo = $request->getParameter("password_nuevo");
                $password_nuevo_rep = $request->getParameter("password_nuevo_rep");
                // storedprocedure que me cambia la pass
                $sql = "USU_ABM_USUARIO_PWD_RS('".$usuario."', '"
                                                                                .$usuario."', 'M', '"
                                                                                .$password."', '"
                                                                                .$password_nuevo."', '"
                                                                                .$password_nuevo_rep."')";

                // ejecuto la query
                $result = BackendServices::getInstance()->getResultsFromStoreProcedure($sql);
                //print_r($result);exit;
                if($result[0]['respuesta'] == "OK") {
                        $this->notices = array(0 => $result[0]['respues_exito']);
                } else {
                        $this->errors = array(0 => $result[0]['respuesta']);
                }
        }
        $this->setTemplate('login');
}
```

el **routing.yml** lo tengo así:

```
sf_guard_signin:
  url:   /login
  param: { module: preinscripciones, action: login }
// lo llamativo es que el module preinscripciones no existe.

sf_guard_signout:
  url:   /logout
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_password:
  url:   /request_password
  param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: password }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

El cambio de password lo hace correctamente. Pero en producción recibo el mensaje de `500 internal server error` mientras que local me sale el mensaje de error correcto.

Alguna idea de qué puede ser? No puedo encontrar el error.
Muchas gracias

**El log dice:**

> [Mon Apr 03 12:12:23 2017] [error] [client 192.xxx.xx.xx] The template "loginSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable in ""., referer: http://"miurl"/

Comment: revisa el archivo de log del entorno de producción, es probable que tenga más información

Comment: [Mon Apr 03 12:12:23 2017] [error] [client 192.xxx.xx.xx] The template "loginSuccess.php" does not exist or is unreadable in ""., referer: http://"mi url"/

El archivo se encuentra en el directorio. LoginSuccess.php se llama

Comment: Pues ese error te está indicando que sf no está encontrando la plantilla loginSuccess.php, la cual debe mostrarse revisa que la declaración `$this->setTemplate('login');` sea correcta.

Comment: $this->setTemplate('login') no lo encuentro más que en el action_class.php
No está declarado en ningún lado. Lo curioso es que local anda bien.